# Is my OAuth2 login secure enough?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, xss, csrf

I am developing an application that communicates with the backend through RESTful APIs only. Now my authentication/authorization are all based on the OAuth2 protocol. I am wondering whether this is secure enough.

My login/logout workflow:

1. Issue an API call to request an access token. The information include: `app_key`, `app_secret`, `username`, `password`, `grant_type`. Store this token in the local storage, indicating this user is logged-in.
2. When requesting some restricted resource, such as `/api/profile`, the front-end send the Ajax request with the `token` in the request header: `Authorization [token]`.
3. The backend retrieves the current user from the `token` and decides whether to allow.
4. For logout, simply remove the token from the local storage.

I am planning to add in HTML encoding (to protect from XSS) and HTTPS (to prevent token explosion).

I am wondering, such kind of "simple" mechanism, is it secure enough to protect my site from common attacks such as CSRF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are sending app_secret from the client. Which means the client has the app_secret, and thus it is leaked to anyone using the site.
2. For OAuth2 it is supposed to be `Authorization: bearer [token]`
3. OAuth2 is not meant for authentication, only authorization. You might want to consider OpenID connect which is based on OAuth2. A token gives the holder access to perform some action, but does prove that the requester is in fact the user, or someone delegated to by the user. Consider an expensive car with a valet key. This key is a token with limited access to the car. Anyone holding this token can drive the car (authorization). However posession of this token, does not prove ownership of the car (authentication).
4. Your logout mechanism doesn't really log the user out, as the token is still valid. So if someone has a copy, that copy would still be valid. You should consider an API call to invalidate the token.

OAauth2 **requires** HTTPS so that needs to be in place.

Comment: Thanks @Erlend. But OAuth2 is not for authentication? I am trying to get a system similar to Google account. Then a Gmail account is able to do authentication, is it? Another point is, I think the client is fine to know the secret, as the client has to register an App to my system before being able to login. It is the client's responsibility to keep the app secret safe, just like a Google App. Am I correct?

Comment: Google is using OpenID connect: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect (It's built on top of OAuth 2)